# python count de diferentes palavras com apenas um contador?

Tags: python, contador

Tenho este código:

```
palavras = dataClean.split()
count = 1

for palavra, frequencia in palavras:
    aleatorio = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
    if aleatorio < 0.5:
        count += 1

    contProb[palavra] = count
    count = 0

print(contProb)
```

Por exemplo, para este txt:

```
olá mundo olá mundo adeus
```

Portanto gostaria que funcionasse desse jeito: no `for`
deve ser capaz de ler cada letra do texto dado e a cada letra incrementar consoante o resultado do `if`. 
Passo a dar um exemplo:
O contador inicia sempre com o valor 1 para todas as letras. Lemos a palavra `ola` na variável `aleatorio` o número random criado é o 0.4, ou seja, deve incrementar 1 ao `count`. Depois disso devemos ler a segunda palavra `mundo` e se, por exemplo, `aleatorio` for 0.3 deve incrementar 1 ao `count` mas o count já é 2, ou seja, ao incrementar vai incrementar o 3 e guardar. E não é isso que deve fazer. 
Ou seja, preciso de vários contadores? Como faço isto

Comment: Amigo, por favor, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/351394/edit) sua pergunta e acrescente um exemplo como ficaria o resultado para este txt que você passou `olá mundo olá mundo adeus`; O que você quer que fique no final? Algo tipo `{'olá': 3, 'mundo': 2, 'adeus': 1}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando essa frase:

```
frase = "olá mundo olá mundo adeus"
palavras = frase.split()
```

Agora podemos usar o `defaultdict` para fazer um dicionário contador que armazena um número inteiro para cada palavra - já configuramos para começar com o valor 1 para todas as palavras:

```
import collections
contador = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
```

Para cada palavra, caso o sorteio dê positivo, incremente o contador daquela palavra específica diretamente:

```
for palavra in palavras:
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        contador[palavra] += 1
```

Comment: Pois é @nosklo. Tem toda a razão, confundi tudo. Vou editar agora mesmo a questão. Agradeço sua ajuda.

Comment: @Walt057 editei a resposta